# Submit a keyword in html and use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to make an html where you enter a keyword.

```
<html>    
  <head>
    <title>Options</title>
  </head>    
  <body>
    <input name="Keyword" type="text">
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </body>    
</html>
```

I want to use that keyword in a javascript between these quotations

```
var shoeName = "";
```

This is for a chrome extension so on the options page I want to enter a keyword, submit it and have it automatically put it into the javascript

Comment: What about to provide an id too and to use GetElementById()?

Comment: set a id for the input text like this `<input id="keyText" name="Keyword" type="text">` & can refer the same in js like this `<script>var shoeName = document.getElementById("keyText").value; </script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting an ID for the element and accessing the element using the ID.

**HTML:**

```
<html>    
    <head>
        <title>Options</title>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <input id="keyText" name="Keyword" type="text">
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </body>    
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    var shoeName = document.getElementById("keyText").value;
</script>
```

Happy coding.

Comment: I don't know why this isn't working.. I want to make a chrome extension that has an options page where you enter a keyword:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748342/submitting-a-keyword-in-html-that-goes-into-javascript

Comment: Well bro, thats seems like a new Question, since you have already created a Question on SO for this, i will check in it, meanwhile lets close this Question as it has served its purpose. you can close this Question by ticket this solution as a answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the input value using

```
shoeName =  $("input[name='Keyword']").val(); // if you can not add id
```

if id can be added just do

```
$('#inputid").val()
```

or if you want data on form submit do

```
<form name="myForm" id="testForm" method="POST" action="send.php"> 
<input name="Keyword" type="text">
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"
</form>

var shoeName = "";

$("form[name='myForm']").submit(function(){
    shoeName =  $("input[name='Keyword']").val()
 // other processing
});
```

Comment: OP was expecting a Pure JS implementation and not Jquery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20748342/submitting-a-keyword-in-html-that-goes-into-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var shoeName;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    document.getElementById('keyword').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        shoeName = this.value;
    });

});
```

Every time text is added to the textbox, `shoeName` is being updated.