# Submitting a Keyword in HTML that goes into Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome-extension

I am looking to make a Chrome extension.. I want an Options Page where you submit a keyword:

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>Options</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    Keyword:<input id="keyText" name="Keyword" type="text">
            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
 </body>
</html>
```

This javascript is supposed to refresh twitter until it find a keyword then clicks on the link in the tweet.
I want this submitted keyword to be put in to a java script into the first var:

```
var shoeName = "";
var nikestore = "nikestore";
var closeFlag = "no";
var tFunction = "twitterScan()";
var tweet = new Array();
var tweetName = new Array();

function twitterScan() {

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    tweetName[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;
    tweet[i] = document.getElementsByClassName("js-tweet-text")[i].innerHTML;

}


//if (document.getElementsByClassName("fullname js-action-profile-name show-popup-with-id")[0].innerHTML;

if (tweet[0].match(shoeName) == shoeName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[0].click();
    tFunction = "get outa here";
    shoeName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to jump out of interval loop

} 

else if (tweet[1].match(shoeName) == shoeName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[1].click();
    tFunction = "get outa here";
    shoeName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to jump out of interval loop

}

else if (tweet[2].match(shoeName) == shoeName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[2].click();
    tFunction = "get outa here";
    shoeName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to jump out of interval loop

}


else if (tweet[3].match(shoeName) == shoeName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("twitter-timeline-link")[3].click();
    tFunction = "get outa here";
    shoeName = " 4444  4 456 7 8 456 7 345 7 345  345 3 1 1 133s "; //buffer to jump out of interval loop

}


else {
    location.reload(true);
}

setTimeout(tFunction, 700);


}

setTimeout(tFunction, 700);

//setInterval("refreshPage()", 3000);
//setTimeout("twitterScan()", 100);
//setInterval(tFunction, 700);
```

Comment: Is the html posted complete? What is the problem your are facing currently? is variable data not coming or some function misbehaving?

Comment: I want the Keyword submitted in the html to be set as the var shoeName in the java script

Comment: @user2125877: I am not sure why `document.getElementById('ketText').val` not working in your case , could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net, will check it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769031/js-not-running-properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
Keyword:<input id="keyText" name="Keyword" type="text">
<input id="submit_button" name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Submit" onClick="javascript: twitterScan();">
```

**JS**

```
<script>
var shoeName = '';
function twitterScan() {
    shoeName = document.getElementById('keyText').value;
    console.log("Iam called " + shoeName);
}
</script>
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/5FDT3/

Let me know if this is what you need

Comment: Sorry I am confused, do you understand that there is two separate documents, one being an html, and the other a .js

Comment: yes i understand that's why i have added as separate in answer, what is the confusion? The JS code that you have provided is loaded on your html page or somewhere else? How you are invoking the js?